# UISlider value in feet and inches

Tags: objective-c, uislider

I am using uislider to set height and height must be in feet and inches. I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me with this.

For now I'm using uislider with NSNumberFormatter. It gives me the values like 5.8, 5.9, 6.0 
but I want it like 5.8, 5.9, 5.10, 5.11, 6.0?

Comment: Does `5.10` mean 5 feet and 10 inches in total?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not do this with one UISlider.

`5` and `11` are not of the same unit, you can not add then by simply put them at both sides of a decimal point. You must convert them into the same unit before addition.

Moreover, the value of a UISlider is decimal. 5.11 is just a number less than 5.9, even than 5.2.

To set the height in feet and inches, you can use two UISlider objects to separately represents feet and inches. Then you can set height like

```
height = sliderForFeet.value + sliderForInches.value/12;
```

or

```
height = sliderForFeet.value*12 + sliderForInches.value;
```